# Warning no esperado

Tags: c, warnings

Estoy pasando una batería de test a un software. Mi intención es pasarle scripts muy sencillos con "putadas" para ver que el sistema funciona correctamente y arroja errores/warnings cuando es debido.

Tengo el siguiente script de test:

```
int f ( char *b )
{
  long int a,c;

  c = (long int)b;
  a = c;
  return 1;
  a = 1;
}
```

El warning que estoy esperando es: `line 9: warning #111-D: statement is unreachable     a = 1;` obviamente porque salgo de la función sin ejecutar esa línea. Pero aparte de ese warning, me arroja el siguiente: `line 4: warning #550-D: variable "a" was set but never used     long int a,c;` (cosa que no quiero que ocurra).

Estoy claramente usando la variable `a` en la asignación `a = c;`, por lo que no entiendo por qué el compilador me arroja ese warning.

Agradezco la ayuda y la explicación sobre por qué se está comportando así el compilador.

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Lee bien el mensaje:

> variable "a" **was set** but never used

El compilador ya sabe que estás dando un valor a `a`. Lo que te está indicando con ese warning es que **no estás usando ese valor para nada**.

Prueba a imprimir el valor de `a` o a usar el valor almacenado en dicha variable de alguna otra forma y el warning desaparecerá.

> Eso he probado a hacer. Incluso retornar el valor return a;, pero la historia es que no puedo añadir/eliminar/modificar las líneas de mi script de test. ¿Hay alguna manera de tocar las bases del compilador para adaptar los requisitos de los warnings/errors?

Hay un truco simple y tonto a partes iguales:

```
(void)a;
```

Lo que esta línea es ... nada!!! simplemente *engaña* al compilador para que le parezca que la variable está siendo utilizada

Comment: Eso he probado a hacer. Incluso retornar el valor `return a;`, pero la historia es que no puedo añadir/eliminar/modificar las líneas de mi script de test. ¿Hay alguna manera de tocar las bases del compilador para adaptar los requisitos de los warnings/errors?

Comment: @Londo Puedes tratar de deshabilitar el warning.  Que compilador usas?

Comment: @Pablochaches gcc 6.3.0 de minGW

Comment: @Londo Con `gcc` puedes añadir `-Wno` seguido del nombre del warning para deshabilitarlo. En este caso tienes que añadir el flag `-Wno-unused-variable` para deshabilitarlo.

Comment: Probaré ambas cosas que me habéis propuesto. Muchas gracias como siempre por la ayuda!